# viewModelScope.launch runs on first call, but is not invoked on subsequent calls after using viewModelScope.launch in another ViewModel

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, viewmodel, kotlin-coroutines

I have a function that makes an asynchronous call to a REST API. The function works well in the `init` block, but when I use `pullRefresh` to call the function executes up to this line, `Log.d("Refresh token", "$accessTokenResponse $userIdResponse")`, but then it is stuck. This happens when I add to the collection that the function is supposed to fetch from another function `collectWaste` (included below), which is located in a different `viewModel`

Here is the function in the `viewModel` that I to call `fetchCollection` from the composable

```
fun retry() {
    collectionListState = CollectionHistoryResource.Loading
    fetchCollection()
}
```

Here is how I am calling the retry function in the composable

```
val refreshing = collectionViewModel.collectionListState is CollectionHistoryResource.Loading

val refreshState =
    rememberPullRefreshState(refreshing, onRefresh = { collectionViewModel.retry() })
```

Below is a copy of the `fetchCollection` function

```
private fun fetchCollection() {
        Log.d("Refresh function", "Fetching collection history")
        val accessTokenResponse = state.get<String>("accessToken")
        val userIdResponse = state.get<Int>("user_id")
        Log.d("Refresh function", "Fetching collection stage 2")
        if (accessTokenResponse != null && userIdResponse != null) {
            Log.d("Refresh token", "$accessTokenResponse $userIdResponse")
            val accessToken = "Bearer $accessTokenResponse"
            viewModelScope.launch {
                try {
                    val responseData =
                        collectionHistoryRepository.getCollection(accessToken, userIdResponse)
                    val list = responseData.data?.map {
                        getCollectionItem(it)
                    }
                    if (list != null) {
                        _collectionList.update {
                            list
                        }
                    }
                    collectionListState = CollectionHistoryResource.Success
                } catch (e: IOException) {
                    Log.d("collection fetch error", "Network failure ${e.message}")
                    collectionListState =
                        CollectionHistoryResource.Error(error = "Could not fetch collection history! Check your connection and try again")
                } catch (e: HttpException) {
                    Log.d("collection fetch error", "Http Error ${e.message}")
                    collectionListState =
                        CollectionHistoryResource.Error(error = "Access to collection history denied! Sign in and try again")
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Below is a copy of the `collectWaste` function that after calling to add to the collection, the `viewModelScope.launch` execution in `fetchCollection` is no longer invoked

```
  fun collectWaste(leaderId: Int?, token: String?) {
    Log.d("Refresh function", "We are collecting")
    _collectUiState.update { currentState ->
        currentState.copy(
            collectNetworkError = false,
            HTTPAuthError = "",
            IOAuthError = ""
        )
    }
    val userId = collectFormState.value.userId
    val quantity = collectFormState.value.quantity
    var token = "Bearer $token"


    if (leaderId == null || leaderId == 0) {
        Log.d("Id Error", "We have an Id error")
        updateCollectErrors(idError = "User does not have permission to collect waste")
        return
    }

    Log.d("Refresh function", "We got to stage 2")

    userIdValidation(userId)
    quantityValidation(quantity)


    if (collectUiState.value.collectUiError) return

    Log.d("Refresh function", "We got to stage 3")

    viewModelScope.launch {
        collectState = CollectResource.Loading
        Log.d("Refresh function", "We got to stage 4")
        try {
            val userBody = collectWasteRepository.collectWaste(
                selectedBlock.id,
                selectedLocation.id,
                quantity.toFloat().toInt(),
                leaderId,
                userId,
                selectedWaste.id,
                selectedWasteType.id,
                selectedZone.id,
                token
            )
            Log.d("Collect successful", "${userBody.success}")
            Log.d("Refresh function", "We got to stage 5")
            collectFormState.value = collectFormState.value.copy(userId = "")
            collectFormState.value = collectFormState.value.copy(quantity = "")
            collectState = CollectResource.Collected
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            Log.d("Collect error", "Network failure ${e.message}")
            _collectUiState.update { currentState ->
                currentState.copy(
                    IOAuthError = "Check your internet connection and try again",
                    collectNetworkError = true
                )
            }
            collectState = CollectResource.NotCollected
        } catch (e: HttpException) {
            Log.d("Collect error", "${e.code()}")

            val errorMessage = if (e.code() == 422) {
                "Please enter valid details including member id"
            } else {
                "Could not collect! Try again later"
            }
            _collectUiState.update { currentState ->
                currentState.copy(HTTPAuthError = errorMessage, collectNetworkError = true)
            }
            collectState = CollectResource.NotCollected
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you determining `viewModelScope.launch` is no longer invoked? I don't see any logs in there.

Comment: @Tenfour04 I use this log `Log.d("Refresh token", "$accessTokenResponse $userIdResponse")` in the `fetchCollection` function. So each time the execution gets here, but does not go any further

Comment: That log message is before the launched coroutine, not inside it. So how are you determining that the coroutine is not running? If you put a log message inside the coroutine, do you see it get logged?

Comment: @Tenfour04 no, a test message inside the coroutine is not being logged as well

Comment: The only possible reason I can think of for a coroutine not getting launched is if you have cancelled the scope previously. Are you calling `viewModelScope.cancel()` anywhere?

Comment: @Tenfour04 I am not canceling it, but this only happens after I call another coroutine in another view model. At launch, it works well, even the pull to refresh feature, but once I open another screen and run `viewModel.launch` there, it no longer launches

Comment: @Tenfour04 I found was clearing the `viewModel` during navigation. I was using `popBackStack()` to navigate out of the screen, which I have learned clears the `viewModel`. Thank you for the help